# How can I import text from a Word doc into Neo4j?

Tags: import, neo4j, ms-word

I'm trying to import the text as a chain of nodes parsing some simple layout tags. What is the best way to get text from Word into Neo4j?

Comment: I'm editing your title and question slightly to be more relevant to what you're actually looking for. Your original question was easily answered by looking at the APOC Procedures documentation (there is no such APOC procedure for this type of import), so what you're really looking for seems to be some alternate means of getting data from Word into Neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has no such functionality, nor do  I expect them to add it.

Neo4j can import CSV files quite well, and I believe there are options (either in Word itself or third party tools) to convert a Word doc to CSV. I would recommend that as your best option for getting data from there into Neo4j.